# ReactDOM not rendering anything from separate js file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, nginx

I used "npx create-react-app testreact" to create a react project. When testing from browser on my PC, the server returns a blank page, other than the expected words —— "Learn React".

What's happening here? how to fix it?

**Cmd Sequnce**

1. npx create-react-app testreact
2. npm install
3. npm start

**Env Info**
nodejs: v13.2.0
npm: 6.13.1
system: 18.04.1-Ubuntu
reverse proxy server: nginx

**Code Info**
repo: https://github.com/nautilusshell/testreact.git
there is folder called node_modules which was created by "npm install", I didn't put into above repo because it is too big and not necessary to upload.

by the way, **actually I didn't change anything**.

**Err Info**
visit http://52.130.83.55/image_editing
from browser I got:
[image]

the .js files whose status equal 404 all locates at http://52.130.83.55/static/js/xxx.js. This path was told by my chrome browser, but I searched my server, by command 
`find / -name "0.chunk.js" 2>/dev/null`, **only to find that there are no such files**.

[image]

For example,  http://52.130.83.55/static/js/0.chunk.js was not found anywhere on my server.

**Nginx Config**
repo: https://github.com/nautilusshell/nginx_config.git

Comment: Can you check your network tab? Is that `index.js` file getting downloaded by the browser correctly?

Comment: @ChaimFriedman no, it prompts some errors

Comment: Please post any errors. Better yet, post a repo (if you changed anything from the standard CRA setup, otherwise, not necessary) and provide your ngnix configuration.

Comment: Please downgrade `node.js` to `^10.16.3` by `nvm`. `npm` is okay with the latest version.

Comment: There is no issue with the Node version here. I am running 13.2 and cloning the repo and running it works fine.

Comment: Please downgrade `node.js` to `^10.16.3` by `nvm`. `npm` is okay with the latest version.

Comment: Steve, are you sure the failing URLs are `/static/*`and not `/public/`?

Comment: @MattCarlotta added detail information about errors and all other necessary elements for solving problem.

Comment: @DanPantry yes, I am sure. the path is shown from my browser.

Comment: @WenchengLi could you please give some more info why to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your nginx configuration has the following block:

```
location /image_editing {
   proxy_set_header Host $host;
   proxy_set_header  x-forwarded-for $remote_addr;
   proxy_set_header  X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
   client_max_body_size 1000M;
   proxy_pass http://image_editing;
}
```

This block presumably points anyone who visits `[hostname]/image_editing` is shown your React App, however it does not *rewrite* the path. This means that if you visit `localhost/image_editing`, the path is still `/image_editing` in the browser.

Any paths to assets, such as `/static/js/bundle.js` (note the leading slash), which is used by default by CRA, will not go to the webserver hosted by Create React App but instead will hit Nginx itself. You have no configuration to forward requests to `/static` to the same server as `/image_editing`, so all of those requests will fail.

In other words, when you visit `yourdomain/image_editing`, the `index.html` of your React app is sent back declaring that all of the assets are located at `http://yourdomain/static`. This request hits Nginx and Nginx correctly serves 404 because it does not know about those assets. You need to configure your React App such that it 'thinks' that the assets are *actually* located at `http://yourdomain/image_editing/static/`.

To solve this, you need to modify the `publicPath` property of the webpack configuration of your project. Unfortunately, this will require *ejecting* your Create React App configuration using `npm eject`.

You could also resolve this on the Nginx side using subdomains. For example, you could host your image editing app at `image-editing.yourdomain.com` and all of the URLs with leading slashes would resolve correctly.

Comment: could you please tell more about: 1. how to solve it by npm method? 2. and how to solve it by nginx method? I am newbie of the nodejs and react stuff, and have spent so much time on this problem. Perhaps I need detailed steps about how to do it. Of course your answer have helped me understand this problem so much.

Comment: You would solve it via npm by entering `npm eject` into your console. This would prevent you from upgrading to future versions of `react-scripts`, but would you complete control over your webpack configuration. From there it's a fairly simple change: https://webpack.js.org/guides/public-path/

Comment: Using Nginx, you have two options. You can forward all requests to `/static` to `http://image_editing` using a new `location` block. You could copy and paste the location block in this answer and replace `location /image_editing` with `location /static` and it should work. However, this would prevent any other application you host within this nginx configuration from using the `/static` path.

Comment: Your other option would be to host your image editing app on a subdomain. This would require you to make a change to your DNS server and use a `server` block in nginx. You can find more information about that [here](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/server_blocks/), although this solution will require more knowledge in Nginx than the other two.

Comment: The simplest solution right now would be to take the location block approach in nginx just to get things working, but you'll want to take a look at either the subdomain approach or npm eject approach in the future as redirecting all `/static` requests to your image editing react app will probably cause hard-to-diagnose issues later on down the road.

Comment: @Steve I've raised a [pull request](https://github.com/nautilusshell/nginx_config/pull/1) against your nginx configuration with the static path approach. :)

Comment: I tried the nginx method by adding one block to config file, it worked!! I saw the expected words!!

Comment: one more question: is it possible to just modify nginx config rules, letting the nginx server forward requests for those image_editing static files to the image_editing service itself, without using the subdomain idea? By rewritign the path in the location image_editing block?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/203418/discussion-between-steve-and-dan-pantry).